# Creating a Service Fabric cluster using resource manager template

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-resource-manager

[image: Capture]

No luck today, I'm receiving an InvalidTempalteDeployment error, I'm using the deploy and parameter json file:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/service-fabric-secure-cluster-5-node-1-nodetype-wad

Error message:

> Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "SF-API-Research" -TemplateFile "D:\Research\101-Azure\SF-API-Re
>   search-ARM-Template\azuredeploy.json" -TemplateParameterFile "D:\Research\101-Azure\SF-API-Research-ARM-Template\azuredeploy.parameters.js
>   on"
>
> Code    : InvalidTemplateDeployment
>
> Message : The template deployment 'a0ece8f8-b9b1-490e-b8c4-61e5ee2fb1ce' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The
>             tracking id is '6f58292f-759e-44b8-8ddf-83e279244a21'. See inner errors for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for
>             usage details.
>
> Details : {Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.PSResourceManagerError,
>   Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.PSResourceManagerError}

Azure portal is showing an **No found** image that prevent me from selecting. I tested with different computers and different browsers.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have to fill all the details in before you can get the custom ARM template. I noticed you missed some information in your screenshot such as node type count.

Comment: I added the correct values in azuredeploy.parameters before invoking the command.

Azure portal display a no found image on top that does not allows me to select node type or any other option.

Comment: Can you take a printscreen?

Comment: the portal image went away after creating an storage account, no sure that it was the reason.

I exported the template from the portal and use azure deployment commend successfully.. thank you

Comment: @YusbelGarcia No probs, you must create a storage account only when exporting the template. Feel free to mark as answer.