# Creating Service Fabric cluster through the portal

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

[image]

Not found image on top of Cluster configuration blade doesn't let me select the values to complete step 2.

Is there any reason?

thank you

Comment: after adding an storage account the image went away

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Service Fabric cluster using resource manager template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39680770/creating-a-service-fabric-cluster-using-resource-manager-template)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Where did you add the storage account ?

Comment: @shekhar - I'm not sure that it have to do with the storage account, I removed the storage account and the image is not showing up anymore. I don't know what actually fix it.